# c#, using .length method

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a method that needs to do a calculation based upon the length of an array. I am using the .length method for the calculation, but the method is doing arithmetic with the max length of the array (which I have declared as 10). This is the loop I am using to get data from the user. I know it isn't the ideal way to sort array data, but this is for a homework assignment, and it revolves around using the .Split method correctly (which isn't the problem I'm having).

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a name and a score for player #{0}: ", (i + 1));
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "")
    {
        // If nothing is entered, it will break the loop.
        break; 
    }

    // Splits the user data into 2 arrays (integer and string).
    string[] separateInput = input.Split();
    name [i] = separateInput[0];
    score [i] = int.Parse(separateInput[1]);
}
```

Here is the method I am using to calculate the average score:

```
static void CalculateScores(int[] score)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += score[i];
        average = sum / score.Length;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The average score was {0}", average);
```

I am calling the method like this:

```
    CalculateScores(score);
```

Edit: My arrays are declared:

```
    int[] score = new int[MAX]; //MAX == 10.
    string[] name = new string[MAX];
```

The CalculateScores method is doing the math as though score.Length is always 10, no matter how many different combinations of scores I input to the console. I can't figure out if it's because my loop to gather input has been done incorrectly, or my CalculateScores method is flawed. Thanks in advance.

Edit: to clarify, I am just confused at why I can't get the correct value out of CalculateScores.

Comment: How is `score` declared?

Comment: where it `MAX` initialized/defined? what are your expectations?

Comment: i'll make an edit, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

`Length` always represents the size of the array, which if you've instantiated as 10, then it will always be 10, regardless of how many items you've filled.

There are lots of ways of solving your problem, but I'd go with the simple one of not using length in your calculation, but rather just storing the number of items in a separate variable:

```
int numItems = 0;
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a name and a score for player #{0}: ", (i + 1));
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "")
    {
        break; // if nothing is entered, it will break the loop
    }
    numItems++;
    ...
}

static void CalculateScores(int[] score, int numItems)
{
    // don't use Length at all, use numItems instead
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Further evidence that I should be using a counter in more of my loops. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problemo - there are a lot more things you can do to make the code better - for example, @Romoku's answer adds a couple good ideas like `List` and `.Average()`, but since you said this was homework, I don't know how much you want to change - I know teachers generally like to stick to the basics rather than using real-world shortcuts.

Comment: Yeah, the code as it is right now isn't what I would like to do, because the whole assignment revolves around using the (array).Split method. But I appreciate your help dumbing down the code to university homework levels haha.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are generally used for fixed sized data, so the `Length` property reflects how many items the array can hold rather than the amount of elements in the array. The simplest fix would be to use a [`List(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), which is used for variadic data, instead.

```
// A nice abstraction to hold the scores instead of two separate arrays.
public class ScoreKeeper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

var scores = new List<ScoreKeeper>();

for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a name and a score for player #{0}: ", (i + 1));
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input == "")
    {
        // If nothing is entered, it will break the loop.
        break; 
    }

    // Splits the user data into 2 arrays (integer and string).

    string[] separateInput = input.Split();

    scores.Add(new ScoreKeeper { Name = separateInput[0], Score = int.Parse(separateInput[1]) });
}

static void CalculateScores(ICollection<ScoreKeeper> scores)
{
    // We take advantage of Linq here by gathering all the
    // scores and taking their average.
    var average = scores.Select(s => s.Score).Average();
    Console.WriteLine("The average score was {0}", average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checking maually:

```
int sum = 0;
int average = 0;
int length;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    if(name[i]!=string.empty) {
        sum += score[i];
        length=i+1;
    }       
}
average = sum / length;
Console.WriteLine("The average score was {0}", average);
```